# How to change aspect ratio of screen

Tags: samsung, screen, system, developer-options, screen-resolution

I am trying to change the aspect ratio of my phone's screen, presumably by changing the resolution, to achieve the result shown in the image.

[image]

I am not trying to just change the resolution without changing the screen size as you would with an app such as 'nomone resolution changer'

I am not trying to hide the top and bottom of the screen as you would with an app such as 'notch hider'

I am not trying to just move the icons on screen as you would with 'adb overscan'

I want the device to behave as if those areas of the screen are not there at all, so they just stay black all the time

I know this will require root so bring on the root solutions

Thanks in advance

Comment: I knew of a root app that does exactly what you wanted. Trying my best rememeber it. WIll put up answer if I do .

Answer (score 0):

[HEBF optimiser](https://github.com/Lennoard/hebf-android) [ROOT] has a screen resolution setting that I guess does exactly what you want.